# Disable address bar and back button in browser in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I disable address bar and back button in browser in html file?

Something Like this :

Here is the demo :http://jsfiddle.net/n5pKP/5/

**JS:**

```
$('.popup').click(function () {
    var curr_browser = navigator.appName;
    if (curr_browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        window.opener = self;
    }
    window.open('http://www.google.com/', 'null', 'width=900,height=750,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,resizable =no');
    window.moveTo(0, 0);
    window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height - 100);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a target="_parent" href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup">Open new window</a>
```

Right now its opening on click. I want to open it directly as popup. Like I double click on test.html , its should appear my html data and disabled address bar and with no back button.

How it can be done?

Comment: Remove the onclick handler?

Comment: it will directly open the popup then, i dont want popup

Comment: you write "*I want to open it directly as popup*" in your question..

Comment: You can't disable back button or address bar without opening a popup.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli As popup not popup

Comment: @putvande Are you sure ?

Comment: @CodeHunter, Are you sure he is not sure?

Comment: as @putvande says, it is not possible. And for good reasons (*security ones and UX*)

Comment: @Alexander I cant give up on doing this, so i must need a solution. If anyone has a solution , i will be thankful

Comment: @CodeHunter can you describe why you want to do this ? what you are ultimately trying to achieve ?

Comment: "As popup not popup" Do less drugs…

Comment: I think by 'directly open as popup' the OP means the page initially opens like that of a popup (having the stuff disabled), which isn't possible unless a different page opens yours.

Comment: @Gary exactly. You are right

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="window.open('WebForm1.aspx','PoP_Up','directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=1024,height=768');" />
```

This is supported in top browser

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript API exists, just that due to security issues, browser vendors disabled the hiding of the address bar.

[Hiding the address bar of a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser)

Instead, you could make a modal within the browser window. Twitter Bootstrap or something like this: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/