# Disable browsers address bar

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I'm going to do a demo of a web app i'm developing. I was wondering if it's possible to disable chrome's address bar. People will be testing the app, so hiding the address will ensure us that they won't be using the computers for facebook or twitter.

Comment: You're looking for "Kiosk mode."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no chrome installed, but I think what you want is kiosk mode.

To start chrome in kiosk mode use the commanline argument –kiosk [Your URL]"
The bad thing is key combinations like alt+f4 are still working.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot remove or hide address bar due to security reason. But you can open the web browser as pop up by disabling the address bar. The main disadvantage is if pop up is blocked then your page will not open.

```
<A HREF="#" onMouseOver="ShowPopUp('\popup.aspx')">Image Name</A>
```

[Disable address bar and back button in browser in html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063682/disable-address-bar-and-back-button-in-browser-in-html-file)