# How to hide the file name and location in address bar

Tags: html

I have a html form localhost/exam/ee2d.html whose action is taken by localhost/exam/e2d.php.

Address bar always shows the name and location of the files I am using. Is there any way to hide this so that others cant guess it.

Comment: Do you use Apache of something else ?

Comment: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/85/Using+.htaccess+rewrite+rules#gs

Comment: [check this post ][1]

this question already in stack overflow 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser

Comment: Xampp, Phpmyadmin, htdocs