# How can I cause windows in chromium to open without toolbar displayed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium

I would like to have all windows in chromium (on linux) open without the toolbar/tab-bar displayed. My research so far has found that when opening a new window with `window.open` in javascript, the toolbar can be hidden by passing `toolbar=0` as an argument. Also, in the javascript console, I can see the value of `window.toolbar` is `BarProp {visible: true}`. However, trying to set this value (by executing `window.toolbar.visible = false`) has no effect - the value remains true and the bar remains visible.

I would like to know two things
- How can I hide the toolbar in the current window (not by opening a new window)?
- Once that is solved, how can I cause that to be done automatically when each new window is opened?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603908/3336376) for a hint that what you want to achieve is not possible for security reasons. And to quote @Quentin in [this other post on the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15926175/3336376): "If you could hide it, then you could use HTML/CSS to make something that looked like a common address bar. You could then put a different address in it. You could then trick people into thinking they were on a different site and entering their password for it."

Comment: @M463 however, I'm asking about what is called the "toolbar", which displays tabs. I'm not asking about the address bar, which the linked question discusses

Comment: I see... sorry for the confusion then, I missed you stated _tab-bar_ in the first sentence.

Comment: @ajp Did you ever find a solution for this? Setting "menubar=0" doesn't work for me.