# mvc hide address bar

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

How to hide address bar in mvc web application? I want to hide that in every view. I have tried by doing this code in javascript:

```
function popup(pageURL, title, popupWidth, popupHeight) {
    window.moveTo(0, 0);                

    var targetPop = window.open(pageURL, title, 'status=no, tmenubar=no, scrollbars=yes, maximize=yes, resizable=no, width=' + screen.availWidth + ',height=' + screen.availHeight, "_blank");
    targetPop.moveTo(0, 0);
    targetPop.focus();
}
```

i call that function on _Layout :

```
<body onload="popup()">
</body>
```

i don't know how to get current url to pass it to the "pageURL" parameter.
or do i do that in a wrong way?

can you guys give me better solutions?

EDITED:

when first time i run the app, it will show the main _Layout and the Index view inside (Renderbody()). how i make the main layout to hide the address bar?
and so if i navigate to another view

Thank You guys.
Sorry for My bad English.

Comment: What is your question?  Are you trying to hide the address bar, or pass in the URL as a parameter?

Comment: use `window.location.href ` or `document.URL;` further information see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46183437)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because it's a request from user, they don't want url is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go try this

```
<body onload="popup(window.location.href, 'New Window', 500, 500)">
</body>
```

To hide address bar its more to tricky way depends on your browser because very browser have different method. Maybe you want to see this
: [Hiding the address bar of a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser)