# How can a jsp based application launch a browser with no window frame or tabs or menu or toolbar

Tags: html, css, jsp, browser

I am looking for a way to launch my application in a browser with window frame or tabs or menu or toolbar, is there any way i could achieve that.

For instance i want to launch my application without the part marked in orange. (without tabs or possibility of creating a new tab) and the settings button beside the address bar

[image]

Update:

i am adding a image of what i am trying to accomplish... 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser

Comment: @rickz thank you i realised that adress bar should not be disabled for security reasons. i was wondering if there is way to launch the browser only with address bar and body without frame, tool bar , menubar or tabs. i have update the image for understanding