# how i can hide URL in the address bar

Tags: javascript, html

i want hide URL in the address bar

example;i have site

```
http://www.example.com/
```

when i open it the url Disappears

may be i can make it  with javascript code

there are a solution

Comment: Uh... no? At least not in modern browsers—that's deemed a security risk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the address bar of a browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in modern browsers since concealing the address of a page aids phishing attacks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any solution to hide the addressbar?

No. If you could hide it, then you could use HTML/CSS to make something that looked like a common address bar. You could then put a different address in it. You could then trick people into thinking they were on a different site and entering their password for it.

It is impossible to conceal the user's location from them because it is essential for security that they know what their location is.