# Hide chrome address bar in angular 2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 2 v.2.2.0 - how to hide address bar in Chrome? May be some `windows.location()` function? Or something else in new component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is not possible for security reasons. 
See more details why on this discussion:

[Hiding the address bar of a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser)

But what you can do is adding a button which activates fullscreen. So the user doesn't have to look for the settings or the shortcut (F11 on Windows). 
And before you ask. Enabling fullscreen without user-interaction isn't allowed either. Again for security reasons.

Comment: is there  another way around it ?