# No URL bar on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I have this wordpress website and don't want the browsers URL bar on mobile devices. It's taking away so much space, especially if the smartphone is in horizontal position. I already searched for solutions on the web but it didnt work as it should. Maybe I just forgot something and couldnt see it.

So the thing should be like this: Once the users interacts (touch, scroll) the URL bar should disappear and should appear just if the top of the page is reached again. So it should be a fullscreen experience.

Now it is working like this: When user is scrolling down and then scrolls up, the URL bar appears even if the top of the page is not reached. And this is something I dont want...disturbs a lot and takes away the whole space needed.

This should work on iOS and Android too.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: play with browser element is quite impossible but you can try to put your web site in fullscreen when user scroll on quit fullscreen mode when user is at the top maybe it can make something like you want. But you need to know that browser behaviour is not editable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hiding the address bar of a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926105/hiding-the-address-bar-of-a-browser)

Answer (score 1):

> Now it is working like this: When user is scrolling down and then scrolls up, the URL bar appears even if the top of the page is not reached. And this is something I dont want...disturbs a lot and takes away the whole space needed.

You will have to live with it. This is a core browser behavior, and cannot (and should not!) be overridden by web sites.