# Using window.open() "windowFeatures" parameter and trying to remove about:blank

Tags: javascript, dom, window

When I use window.open() method, I'm using the windowFeatures parameter to try to turn off the bar that, in my case has "about:blank" in it.

[image: about blank bar]

I'm trying to get rid of the horizontal bar that, in my case, contains the "about:blank" line. I've tried all the documented stuff but cannot seem to turn it off.

Any ideas?

I checked the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), and tried all the windowFeatures, but none of them seem to turn that particular part of the window off.

```
myNewWindow = window.open("", "Details", "width=600,height=500,left=200,top=200,menubar=off,toolbar=off");

myNewWindow.write('<html><head></head><body>Yadda yadda</body></html>');
```

Comment: you can't: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15926175/1444609

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dup. Didn't search right first.